# How to simulate ThisPresentation in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to be able to access the document properties of a PowerPoint add-in file (a presentation saved as "PowerPoint Add-in (*.ppa)", from some VBA code in the add-in itself.

If it helps to understand the problem, what I'm actually trying to do is read a custom document property that stores the version number of the add-in, so that I can display that in a dialog box.

With Word & Excel I can do this using `ThisDocument` & `ThisWorkbook`, both of which return a reference to the document containing the running code. However, there is no `ThisPresentation` equivalent in PowerPoint.

For a standard PowerPoint presentation or template, I could use `ActivePresentation`. However, this method won't work for an add-in.

Any ideas? Please, no suggestions about where else I should stick the version number :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REVISED FEB 2, 2010: Cleaned up answer to only show the final solution**

---

Here's the way to do what was asked, no DLLs. Really simple:

```
Sub ReturnPPAasPresentation()
    Dim p As Presentation
    Set p = Presentations("presentation1.ppa")
    Dim title As String, version As String
    version = p.CustomDocumentProperties("Version").Value
    title = p.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value
    MsgBox "Version: " & version & " of " & title, vbOKOnly, title
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I don't think this does solve my particular problem. It covers various scenarios, but not one in which an **add-in** needs to get a reference to itself. Even using Addins(myName) would only give me a reference to an AddIn object, which doesn't let me get at the document properties, etc. of the add-in. Still, thanks for trying!

Comment: The add-in *does* actually have document properties, in that you can still get and set the properties via Windows Explorer. But, I've come to the conclusion that it's simply not possible to access that through code (or at least not through the VBA object model). Thanks for trying, but I think it's time to give up.

Comment: Erm, yes, I can define the constant in the code - and I could then report it using MsgBox rather more easily than creating a textbox :-)  But, as I said in my question, I'm not really interested in doing it *in a different way* - I'm more interested in whether it's theoretically possible to access the doc props. (And I think I have my answer - it's not).

Comment: Got it. I don't have the PPT doc properties exposed in Windows Explorer on my box - just the add-in properties (name, type, etc.) and any custom properties I want to set. This is consistent with COM Add-ins, of which a PPA is the same thing with just a different file extension. Does yours have the PPT document properties (i.e. BuiltInProperties) like "Title", "Subject", "Author", "Typist",  etc. in Windows Explorer? If so, what versions of PPT and Windows are you using - it's just I've never heard of this before and I'm interested to know.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected. It appears at least some of the original BuiltInDocumentProperties are retained in a PPA. I can't confirm if CustomDocumentProperties are as well.

Here's a DLL that will allow you to read document properties. It *may* work for you. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351/en-us

Comment: OK, after all that effort, I can't possibly *not* accept your answer :-)  It's not a solution I would actually use in practice, because of the deployment issues (everyone needs to install DsoFile), but yes, it would work. Thanks for all your effort!

Comment: Sure, understood about the deployment issues. The DSO source is in C++, but maybe it can be ported to VBA to reside within your PPA.

Comment: Okay, it can be done, really simple. Just assume the PPA can be part of the presentations collection and you've got it. Final revision above!

Comment: This does not work. In Excel, ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook or add-in running the code. It returns the right workbook or add-in, even if the user has renamed the workbook or add-in. In ThisDocument, Word does the same thing. PowerPoint is sorely lacking this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone else I expected a ThisPresentation object in PowerPoint. I thought of another way to accomplish it, without a hardcoded filename. Obviously any piece of code would need to know how to distinguish between the projects. I chose to use the projectname for this (default name "VBAProject" in the Project Explorer): it is not used for anything else, no user will change it and if it is protected they can't.

Here is my code (change MyProject into your own projectname):

```
Function ThisPresentation() As Presentation
Dim p As Presentation

For Each p In Presentations
    If p.VBProject.Name = "MyProject" Then
        Set ThisPresentation = p
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: If you have an add-in (.ppa) loaded, it doesn't show up in the `Presentations` collection...

Comment: @Gary: didn't know that... just made my first PowerPoint macro :-)

Comment: @Gary: I used this in a .pptm file myself. Until last week I never made a PowerPoint macro (I do have a lot of other VBA experience), so I'm not familiar with all PowerPoint-specifics in VBA. But it does work like a charm in a regular macro-enabled presentation (.pptm) in PowerPoint 2010.

One thing though... an add-in is not a presentation. Why expect/desire a ThisPresentation object instead of a ThisAddIn object or so?

Comment: As I said in my question, for macro-enabled presentation you don't need to go to all this trouble - just use `ActivePresentation`.

Comment: "An add-in is not a presentation. Why expect/desire a ThisPresentation object instead of a ThisAddIn object or so?" -- In Word, you create an add-in by taking a Document and saving as an add-in; it's still represented as a document, and you access it via ThisDocument. Same in Excel (ThisWorkbook). Since the process is identical in PowerPoint (take a presentation, save as...) then I'd turn it around and say why would it be different? Anyway, there is no ThisAddin, so it's a moot point.

Comment: Yeah, and if I have two different versions of the add-in open, both with the same VB Project name, I'm still hosed.

Comment: This also relies on the user trusting access to the VB project object model.

Answer (score -1):

Credit goes to macnerd nerd for the general idea, but added the AddIn functionality that was requested by the OP. Unfortunately, AddIns don't have VBProject names, so not quite as robust:

```
Function ThisPresentation(project_name As String) As Object
Dim p As Object

all_presentations = Array(Application.AddIns, Application.Presentations)
For Each pArray In all_presentations
    For Each p In pArray
        Debug.Print p.FullName
        If InStr(p.FullName, project_name) > 0 Then
            Set ThisPresentation = p
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
Next
End Function
```