# Copying table from Excel to PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error

> "Object variable or with block variable not set"

There seems to be an error with
`PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse`

```
Sub Range()
    Dim XLApp As Excel.Application
    Dim PPSlide As Slide

    Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    XLApp.Range("A1:C12").Copy
    PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
End Sub
```

-- Updated

```
Sub Tabletoppt()
Dim XLApp As Excel.Application
Dim PPSlide As Slide

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11)
Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
XLApp.Range("A1:C12").Copy
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse

End Sub
```

I am getting an error "Object required"

Comment: `PPSlide` is `Nothing`. The variable is empty and not initialized yet. Therefore you cannot use it to paste something (you cannot paste into nothing). No object was set to `PPSlide` that is actually what the error tells you. Tell VBA what `PPSlide`  is by referencing the variable to some slide using `Set`. • Another recommendation: Don't name your procedure `Range()` this word is a reserved word in Excel and therefore should not be used as procedure or variable name, or it might cause odd issues.

Comment: The idea is to copy a table from Excel worksheet to powerpoint using VBA. Would you please help with the code with what you want to say?

Comment: As I said you need to define what `PPSlide` should be and `Set PPSlide` to your desired slide. VBA does not know yet which slide `PPSlide` is (you didn't tell VBA it is not `Set` in your code). We cannot tell you which slide you want to paste to, that is something you should know or decide.

Comment: Now `myPresentation` is a empty variable and not `Set`. You need to define what  `myPresentation` is. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472418/how-to-simulate-thispresentation-in-powerpoint-vba • Every variable needs to be declared (eg using `Dim`) and objects need to be `Set`.