# How do I get a reference to a module's presentation?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've experienced situations when a macro of some opened presentation in the background runs while another presentation is active in the foreground. Thus `Application.ActivePresentation` is not appropriate in the case it should work on the specific presentation where it has been defined.

As a workaround I'm using something like that:

```
Const PRESENTATION_NAME = "My Presentation"

Sub MyMacro()
  On Error Resume Next
    Presentations(PRESENTATION_NAME).Windows(1).Activate
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

This works as long as the file name does not change. So I want a name independent solution.

What I'm looking for is something like this pseudo code:

```
Set myPresentation = MyModule.Presentation
```

I.e. get the definer context.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Typically,  for office apps. its best to assign a reference to your 'object' to a variable so that all references to your object pass through the variable  i.e.  
Dim myP as Presentation: set myP = Presentations.Item(PRESENTATION_NAME)

If you install the free and fantastic (open source) Rubberduck addin for VBA you will get lots of advice from the code ispections about this issue.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue that you need a fixed file name (`PRESENTATION_NAME`)

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472418/how-to-simulate-thispresentation-in-powerpoint-vba